# Useing python to download a file in google drive that is created by a google app script

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Ok so I've got a google script that I'm working on to help out with some stuff and I need to be able to create a txt file and download it to my local computer. I've figured out how to create the file as a blob and create a file in google drive.

The problem is that I for one can't figure out how to delete the old file and create the new file and I also can't seem to figure out how to download it locally so I can work my python magic and create a nice looking report and print it out. I've gone over the documentation and looked at similar questions but I can't figure out how to actually download a file.

An example program would be great answer for me something that uses a dummy file and downloads it, really that would be awesome.

My thoughts are that I could go back to the old file that I am trying to download and just edit it so that way I don't have to actually delete the file which would make it have the same ID's, meta data, and URL.

Can I use the google app script to download it directly to my computer and for a little added info I run a Linux machine so some things are a little more labor intensive for me while some other stuff is nice and easy. I feel like there is an app that can run on my computer locally that stores my google drive files locally and I could possibly just grab it from there.

Lastly a link to documentation for running the scripts natively would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to download a file in google drive using Python.

```
# sample
import googleDriveAccess
ci = googleDriveAccess.readClientId(basedir)
ds = googleDriveAccess.second_authorize(basedir, ci, script=True)
id, fileobj = googleDriveAccess.script_download(ds, folder, SCRIPT_ID)
```

source code of googleDriveAccess:
https://github.com/HatsuneMiku/googleDriveAccess

Apps Script Crash Course: Import/Export Apps Script Code
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEVMu9KE6jk

Google Drive SDK: Searching for files
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOSvQmQK_HA

Answer (score 0):

use

```
urllib.retrieve(httpaddressofthefile, filenametosaveitto)
```

or

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.wherever.com/')
html = response.read()
f=open(filename, 'w')
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

Comment: That will only get the meta data and webpage of google drive document, google does some nice stuff to try and make sure you can't just grab a document from them. It also ruins any normal stuff like that.

Comment: Can you give an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Okay what you are looking for is [pydrive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive/1.0.0)

Its a google drive API made just for uploading/downloading google drive stuff.

also @example request:

here:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Author:      Amazingred
# Created:     0017032814
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import urllib, urllib2, os, sys

#The pydrive package download
page='https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyDrive/PyDrive-1.0.0.tar.gz'
request=urllib.urlretrieve(page, 'pydrive.tar.gz')
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"pydrive.tar.gz")):
    print "YUP THE FILE EXISTS"
else:
    print "nope"
```